# How to edit values in sql access with Distinct?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to edit values in sql access with Distinct?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProdutosOrcamento.IDProdutoOrc, ProdutosOrcamento.Produto, ProdutosOrcamento.PrecoOrc, ProdutosOrcamento.IPIOrc, detOrcamentos.IDOrcamento
FROM ProdutosOrcamento LEFT JOIN detOrcamentos ON ProdutosOrcamento.IDProdutoOrc=detOrcamentos.IDProdutoOrc
WHERE (((detOrcamentos.IDOrcamento)=[Formulários]![Orcamentos]![IDOrcamento]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY` for that matter) in your SQL statement, MS Access will consider the query to be read-only.

A possible work-around is to make a new simple editable `SELECT` query that usea an `IN()`  statement on the ID field.

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM ProdutosOrcamento WHERE ProdutosOrcamento.IDProdutoOrc IN
(SELECT ProdutosOrcamento.IDProdutoOrc
FROM ProdutosOrcamento LEFT JOIN detOrcamentos ON ProdutosOrcamento.IDProdutoOrc=detOrcamentos.IDProdutoOrc
WHERE (((detOrcamentos.IDOrcamento)=[Formulários]![Orcamentos]![IDOrcamento])))
```

Comment: Hi, you understand that I need to edit the values​​, but they appear only once?
You show me an example of your explanation, please?

Comment: I've edited again, have another try.  I've used a different approach that should work.

Comment: in this situation i edit the ProdutosOrcamento, but if i edit detOrcamentos i dont alter the query, how edit this?

Comment: Since in your question you used `Distinct`, I presume that there can be many `detOrcamentos` records for each `ProdutosOrcamento` record.  In a query you can't edit records on the many side of a relationship without showing the record on the one side of the relationship as many times as there are records on the many side.  However, using Access, you may be able to have the `detOrcamentos` records in a subform or Subdatasheet which can be edited as a separate recordset.